# ClientRoleProvider and role caching

Tags: .net, membership-provider

Is it possible to disable to the role caching when using the ClientRoleProvider?

The application in question is a console application...

I've tried setting 'cacheRolesInCookie' to false (I know it's a console app, but I was running low on ideas!) - but it had no affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created my own implementation of the RoleProvider due to the caching problem and other business needs.